# Adding separator to a number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a number of unknown length and i need to format it by adding comma after every 3rd number from the right (so **12345678** becomes **12,345,678**). As of now i'm using this chaos to do it

```
value.toString().split('').reverse().join('').match(/.{1,3}/g).reverse().map( (num) => num.split('').reverse().join('') ).join()
```

Is there any cleaner way to do it with native functionality?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out below the simplest way to do this:

```js
let number = 12345678;

console.log(number.toLocaleString("en"));
```

**Reference** -> [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)