# How do append characters at some index inside string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, format

I have requirement to split huge numbers in a format separated by `commas` but at the last 3 character i want to put comma before . for e.g `426,753,890` for such i want to put like `42,67,53,890`

```js
  function numberWithCommas(x) {
    var parts = x.toString().split(".");
    parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    return parts.join(".");
  }
  
  console.log(numberWithCommas(426753890));
```

Comment: You want commas every 2 digits, except for the last 3 digits? That's a very strange format.

Comment: @Barmar It's what is used in the [Indian system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system). Not that strange, really :-)

Comment: Also the way you are adding comma after 3 digit is also bit lengthy. You can simply do it by `number.toLocaleString("en")`. Check this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50839440/631803

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `number.toLocaleString("en-IN")` JavaScript API. `number.toLocaleString()` is pretty useful.

Check below examples:

```js
let number = 426753890;

console.log(number.toLocaleString("en")); // General English format

console.log(number.toLocaleString("en-IN")); // Indian English format
```

Check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Correcting @VicJordan's answer, if you use `en-IN` locale, you should be able to get the formatted string correctly:

```js
let number = 12345678;
console.log(number.toLocaleString("en-IN"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tricky example to do so...

```js
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    var parts = x.toString().split(".");
    parts[0] = parts[0].substring(0, parts[0].length-1).replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + parts[0].substring(parts[0].length-1);
    return parts.join(".");
  }
  
  console.log(numberWithCommas(426753890));
```